# SSRS category groups

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I'm traying to sum all of the BA_CODE and group it into months. Can't find a way to solve it. Any help wil do. Thanks so much!

I already tried to remove one category group but the other filter won't display the right data.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8qSps.png)

Answer (score 1):

There are few possible solutions for this problem.

1. Instead of adding 2 parent group, try to add a child group inside the parent group. It may work sometime.
2. Use sub report to sum up the BA_CODE and add it to the main report then group the main report by months.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I'll try it now.